# Swift: Gesture in cell TableviewCell not working

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uipangesturerecognizer

I want to add a UIGestureRecognizer in UITableViewCell but it does not work.

Here is my code:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    //On lien le TableViewCell
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as? FeedCell
    cell?.selectionStyle = .none

    let pan = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(cell?.handlePan(recognizer:)))
    pan.delegate = self as? UIGestureRecognizerDelegate
    cell?.dragButton.addGestureRecognizer(pan)

    cell?.view(post: posts[indexPath.row], user: users[indexPath.row]); //On passe l'objet a l'index i a la fonction view du TableViewCell pour l'affichage

    return cell!;
}
```

and in tableviewcell

```
@objc func handlePan(recognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    let translation = recognizer.translation(in: dragButton)

    recognizer.view!.center = CGPoint(x: recognizer.view!.center.x + translation.x, y: recognizer.view!.center.y + translation.y)

    recognizer.setTranslation(CGPoint.zero, in: self.containerDragView)
}
```

It does not work I can not drag my imageview

What should I add for my tableview to execute my gesture?

The final result I want when I slide the right or left button right or left images widens in width

thank you

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hBF86.png)

Comment: what is dragButton ?

Comment: it's the imageview that I want to move in the cell

Comment: The blue dot is the cell ?

Comment: Yes, its imageview in the cell

Answer (score 0):

Try this implement delegate `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate` in your tableviewcell class.

I think issue is here. `pan.delegate = self as? UIGestureRecognizerDelegate`

Set delegate this way.

```
pan.delegate = cell
```

Comment: Not work.. look at the picture of my post. I want the blue round imageview in the middle, I want to drag it right or left. when I slide it right it is the image on the left that grows bigger, and when I slide it to the left is the right image that grows bigger

Comment: There are two parts to this. First: Is your pan gesture recognizer calling back to the action method? Second: Is the action method code moving the view? Sheik is right that the cell needs to be the delegate. Actually I would add the gesture recognizer in the cell's awakeFromNib() method. Also you should not need to typecast self as adopting the protocol. Your code should explicitly adopt the protocol.

Comment: Should work. Can share code file with me mshauket.developer@gmail.com